# Action in CCCallFuncN that is used with CCSequence

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I need to create repeatable sequence of actions (CCMoveBy, CCMoveTo), but they need to use random params (position, duration). I wrote 2 methods:

```
-(void) randomizeVec
```

and

```
-(void) calcTiltDuration
```

In fact, those params depends on external variable (factor). I can't do something like that:

```
id randomize = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(randomizeVec)];
id calcTilt = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(calcTiltDuration)];
CCMoveBy* tilt = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:mTIltDuration position:randomVec];
CCMoveTo* restore = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:mTIltDuration position:initialTowerNodePos];
CCDelayTime* wait = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1];
CCSequence* seq = [CCSequence actions:wait,calcTilt,randomize, tilt, restore, nil];
[aNode runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq]];
```

because values are copied once and randomizeVec and calcTiltDuration don't affect actions, so I wrote a method:

```
-(void) moveRandomVector:(CCNode*) node
{
    int dx = rand_between(-1, 2) * mShakeFactor *2 ;
    int dy = rand_between(-1, 2) * mShakeFactor *2;
    CCMoveBy* action = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.1/mShakeFactor position:CGPointMake(dx, dy)];
    CCMoveTo* action2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1/mShakeFactor position:initialTowerNodePos];
    CCEaseInOut* easyTilt = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action rate:0.1];
    CCEaseInOut* easyRestore = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:action2 rate:0.1];
    CCSequence* seq = [CCSequence actions:easyTilt,easyRestore , nil];
    [node runAction:seq];
}
```

which is called via CCCallFuncN:

```
id action = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveRandomVector:)];
CCSequence* sq = [CCSequence actionOne:action two:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1]];
[towerNode runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sq]];
```

The factors change (mShakeFactor) in external methods.

Is it proper approach? I'm not Cocos2d expert and I worry about situation when action that runs sequence with CCCallFuncN in it stops but, CCMove* actions and others in moveRandomVector don't. Maybe you know different approach that I could implement?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I moved the code responsible for starting actions to update method. Each time update is called I check if I can run sequence of actions (Boolean variable). If I can I run it and then set the variable to NO, but after last action in sequence I call method, which checks if I can run sequence again. It is comfortable, because it allows me to change variables that affect actions (CCMoveBy, CCMoveTo) and it resembles CCRepeatForever.